# Win2012 DNS static redirects from C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Tags: networking, dns, hosts-file, windows-server-2012

currently I'm using static redirects to localhost in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts for a low level and fast spam, maleware, ad, etc. protection. Since there is a Win2012 DNS-Server around I want to centralize that setting.

Is there a way to "import" the configuration from C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts into a Win2012 DNS-Server?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Hosts files are specific to each machine. But here is what you can do with some scripting ability.

Setup AD to start a logon script for each end user. In the logon script have some logic that does the following:

> 1. copies the host file you want to correct directory
> 2. Flushes the DNS Cache

This would automate that process for you outside of DNS and give you exactly what you're looking to do.